# { ...action.response } what is the use of that 3 dots in react.js or redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

what is the use of that 3 dots in react.js or redux

```
const something = (state = initState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case something:
          return { ...action.response };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Comment: The answers you've received are correct, but if you want more background, check out [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/why-react-and-redux-need-immutable-data-dae3ab3611a0) I just found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a ES6 feature, spread arrow operator. The spread syntax allows an
>   expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments or
>   multiple elements are expected.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let b = [...a, 5,6,7];
console.log(b); //1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called the spread syntax and it is used to create a shallow copy of an object or an array [...array]. On of main uses in React is creating a copy so that you do not mutate original data when updating the state:

```
[state, setState] = useState(...);
const tempState = {...state};
tempState.key = newValue;
setState(tempState);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

But beware, shallow copy means that only the top keys and values are really created new, nested keys and values are referenced to the original object. That can create errors, so with nested objects and arrays it is preferable to use a library for deep cloning, such as cloneDeep from Lodash.

https://alligator.io/js/deep-cloning-javascript-objects/

Comment: is it take the copy of array.

Comment: In this case it is a shallow copy of an object (action.response). Spread syntax for an array would be [...action.response].